# Show FB status update popup on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook

I have this code which allows the user to update their fb status on my page:

```
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'**', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
  </script>
 </body>
```

It works fine but when the page loads it automatically shows the popup, but I want the box to only show when I press a button. Is this possible? I don't see an option in the FB Documentation.

Comment: Do you need a solution in jQuery? why did you add the jquery tag?

Comment: Does not have to be for jQuery but I already have jQuery on the page so if any of the solutions are written for jQ it's ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[demo](http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/e3ded) ("An error occurred. Please try again later." is showing because I have wrong appID specified)

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'**', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });

     $(function(){ 
          $("#post-wall").click(function(){
              FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
                 message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
              return false;
          });
      });
   </script>
   <a href="#" id="post-wall">Post feed on your wall</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You should be including the jQuery library in the body tag and use the [latest](http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js) ;-)

Comment: @ifaour: I'm including 1.5, because I taken it from my website. will change it, but it's not necessary ;)

Comment: Accepted, would the code be hard to modify to make it a toggle? Doesn't have to be, just wondering.

Comment: @Charlie: Toggle like open-close? I am scared it isn't possible cross-browser

Comment: Yeah toggle that way. I doubt it would be, however this is an app of sorts targeted at Safari.

Comment: @genesis,may I ask you to have a visit at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554666/type-show-a-name-list-like-facebook-status-box ? I do not know whether such a request is valid here in SOF.

Answer (score 1):

```
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'**', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
     function showMessage() {
        FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
           message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
     }

     $('.showMessage').click(function() {
        showMessage();
     });
  </script>

  <a href="javascript:;" class="showMessage">Show Message</a>
 </body>
```

Comment: Pressing the button does not show or hide the popup. Does it use jQuery? Did it work for you?

Comment: @Charlie, yes it uses jQuery even though it's not loaded.

Comment: well you added jquery to your tags, I  thought you were using it

Comment: @SoufianeHassou: yes he added. So did I posted solution with jQuery :)

Comment: Right. I have jQ already loaded on the page, but clicking the button does not run the showMessage function.

Comment: @Charlie: make sure your code is inside $(document).ready and that you have the correct classname

Comment: Make sure the code you posted is in the $(document).ready or the jQ script?

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<head>
  <title>My Great Website</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="open_fb_dialog()">Open Dialog</button>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js">
  </script>
  <script>
     FB.init({ 
        appId:'XXXXXX', cookie:true, 
        status:true, xfbml:true 
     });
    function open_fb_dialog() {
     FB.ui({ method: 'feed', 
        message: 'Facebook for Websites is super-cool'});
    }
  </script>
 </body>
</html>
```

Just put it inside a function and call the function on your action button (`<button>`, `<a>`..etc)